# Failing to create an unique ID with recursion

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module-pattern, revealing-module-pattern

I was trying to solve that problem : http://exercism.io/exercises/javascript/robot-name/readme but I'm stuck on the last requirement. Let me copy the problem

> Write a program that manages robot factory settings.
>
> When robots come off the factory floor, they have no name.
>
> The first time you boot them up, a random name is generated, such as
>   RX837 or BC811.
>
> Every once in a while we need to reset a robot to its factory
>   settings, which means that their name gets wiped. The next time you
>   ask, it will respond with a new random name.
>
> The names must be random: they should not follow a predictable
>   sequence. Random names means a risk of collisions. Your solution
>   should not allow the use of the same name twice when avoidable. In
>   some exercism language tracks there are tests to ensure that the same
>   name is never used twice.

This is the test suite : http://exercism.io/exercises/javascript/robot-name. I manage all of the tests except the last ones (related to unique reset).

My code in revealing module pattern

```
// To avoid duplicates
nameDb = {};

function Robot () {
  var name = '';

  // Helpers
  var randomizeLetter = function() {
    var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    var charToChose = randomizeNumber(1, 26);
    return chars[charToChose - 1];
  };

  var randomizeNumber = function(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  };

  var nameGenerator = function() {
    var min = 100;
    var max = 999;
    var output = '';

    output += randomizeLetter();
    output += randomizeLetter();
    output += randomizeNumber(min, max);
    return output;
  };

  // Called on reset
  var reset = function reset() {
    var candidat = nameGenerator();
    if (name != '') delete nameDb[this.name];
    name = '';

    if(candidat in nameDb) {
      reset();
      return;
    } else {
      nameDb[candidat] = true;
      this.name = candidat;
    }
  };

  // Called immediately
  var newRobot = function newRobot() {
    var candidat = nameGenerator();

    if(candidat in nameDb) {
      newRobot();
      return;
    } else {
      nameDb[candidat] = true;
      name += candidat;
    }
  }();

  return {
    name: name,
    reset: reset
  };
}

module.exports = Robot;
```

Which returns `expected 9767 to equal 10001'`

What I was trying to do is : when the object is first invoked it has a name property. When the reset is called the name property is set to 0 and the corresponding DB entry is deleted. Then when the name is called again I try give a new one with recursion (which must be unique to that object instance). As you can see it doesn't work because the test doesn't returns 10001 unique ids

Comment: var reset = function() {
    this.name = 'new name';
  }

Comment: for some reason I thought it wasn't necessary.. but yeah I'm still stuck after that because I have to reinit the name.. Though I could update the name without this in the newRobot function ?

Comment: You need to keep scope in mind with javascript, and it gets complicated when you do things like this. To solve your second problem, change your reset function to: function() { this.name = nameGenerator(); } and add nameGenerator to your initial return object: return {
    name: name,
    reset: reset, nameGenerator:nameGenerator
  }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expose private variables in Revealing Module Pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672084/expose-private-variables-in-revealing-module-pattern)

Comment: thanks dbugger, and I edited my question so it can't be a duplicate. As you can see a single reset is ok, bu I fail to create an unique id for each reset

Comment: One problem is that your recursion is called like this: `reset();`, in which case you're obliterating the meaning of `this`, which you use in the reset function. You should either be using closures to avoid the `this` keyword, or else you need to make sure to always call `this.reset()`, etc.

Comment: thanks christopher davies it was indeed this.reset() in the recursion.. I'll be honest I'm not sure why as you can see my knowledge of scope and recursion is not good. I will read more about them